# Pasar variable mediante enlace

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

He hecho una pequeña base de datos en phpmyadmin donde obtengo a través de un formulario información referente a varios libros "id, autor, nombre, titulo, etc". La cuestión es que quiero que a partir de un index.php principal donde se encuentra la página donde se obtienen los datos pueda insertar un enlace que me recoja la información de otro libro con otro id distinto, que en este caso será la clave principal. Es decir que desde el index principal pueda a través de enlaces recogerme la información de libros con otro id distinto.

He visto que se puede hacer pasando variables mediante enlace. He hecho lo siguiente, pero no consigo que me recoja la información del libro con el id en cuestión. `

```
                <div class='contenedorEnlaces'>


                    <a class='enlaceLibro' href='index.php?id=3'>Primero</a>
                    `
```

Comment: ¿Que hace index.php? ¿Que hace libro2.php? PD: phpmyadmiun no es una bbdd si no un gestor.

Comment: index.php básicamente rescata los datos de las variables asignadas a los distintos campos de la tabla en phpmyadmin. libro2.php nada, es un enlace.

Comment: Pon el codigo de index.php si no no se entiende muy bien.